# Hashmap key inside value object paradigm

Tags: java, design-patterns, hashmap, bukkit, code-organization

I have this design pattern that occurs whenever I use maps. I find myself having the key of the map also inside of the value. For example:

```
private Map<UUID, PlayerData> allPlayerData = new HashMap<>();
```

Within this example, I have UUID is the key, and I also have the UUID inside of the PlayerData object.

My question is, is this an acceptable pattern of design or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: It is a very common pattern. I don't think it is a problem.

Comment: Yes.  Consider a `Map<Integer, Student>` so that one may easily retrieve the `Student` for a given integer `Id`.  It is very normal for the `Id` to be a field in the `Student` class.

Comment: Make sure that the UUID field of PlayerData is immutable, because if for some reason it changed your map would no longer have the correct mapping.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common and convenient pattern when you want fast access to objects in some collection based on some property of the object itself. Keep in mind that even though the reference to this 'duplicate' property is used in two places, the value is still only once in memory (with an exception of (small) primitives).

Answer (score -2):

Actually it is not design pattern, however don’t see any issue with this either.

Having HashMap as some sort of index or caches, with key generated from value attribute is used quite often.